# How to add a filter to the get_body_class function?

Tags: filters, hooks

I see it is possible to use add_filter with the [`body_class` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class), but I'm needing to add one to the `get_body_class` function.

How can I add a filter to a function that is not included in the [list of already available filter hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body_class()` function simply calls the `get_body_class()` and creates a HTML class string from it.

```
function body_class( $class = '' ) {
    echo 'class="' . join( ' ', get_body_class( $class ) ) . '"';
}
```

So, the `body_class` filter applies to both functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw that in /wp-includes/post-template.php, and this is working, but I'm confused as to why. I added add_filter('body_class', 'my_handler'); in the plugin I'm writing. When I called get_body_class in a page template, it correctly returned the filtered class string. Perhaps I'm not understanding filters correctly, but if body_class is calling get_body_class (and not the other way around), why is this filter, which is added to body_class() also applied to get_body_class()? Just curious.